# MySQL showing name insead of id from other table

Tags: php, mysql, join, syntax

What I want to do is to show the name from the referred table and not the id that I'm obviously getting.

Here is the table I'm displaying on my website. "jid" is just for A_I so every new connection gets a new id.

[image]

This is how all other tables are set up.

[image]

So, from what I know I have to make JOINs to be able to show the name instead of the id, but I have been trying to make my own syntax from other suggestions but I haven't been able to figure it out.

This is one I've tried

```
$query = "SELECT joined.categoryid, category.name 
FROM joined 
INNER JOIN category 
ON  joined.categoryid = category.categoryid";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
```

Comment: It would help if you showed the join query you tried. Then, we could help correct it.

Comment: So the names of your tables are **joined** and **category**?

Comment: Yes, I use joined to gather information from all other tables with foreign key. Category, city, etc. In each of these tables as you can see is the ID and name. I can easily show the id in the browser since I only have to make a while loop that looks inside the joined table, but I want to show the name!

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php

$result = mysql_query("SELECT joined.categoryid, category.name, category.categoryid
FROM joined
JOIN category
ON joined.categoryid = category.categoryid", $db);
 if (!$result) {
 die("Database query failed: " . mysql_error());
 }

 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
 echo "<h2>";
 echo $row[1]."";
 echo "</h2>";
 echo "<p>";
 echo $row[2]."";
 echo "</p>";
 }
?>
```

I tried this myself here is my Output

http://prntscr.com/7ohruc

Comment: I tried this, it still shows the id and not the name

Comment: Have you tried just SELECT category.name ??

`SELECT joined.categoryid, category.name, category.categoryid`

Comment: I tried with 'SELECT category.name', if I understand you correctly. Now it doesn't show anything.

Comment: hvae you tried 

`"SELECT *
FROM joined join, category cat
WHERE  join.categoryid = cat.categoryid";`

Comment: Hey I Edited the Answer Above,

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
"SELECT joined.categoryid, category.name
FROM joined, category
WHERE joined.categoryid = category.categoryid";
```